# Java 8 collector for Guava ImmutableTable using HashBasedTable as accumulator gives IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collectors

Process list of string via method which returns `ImmutableTable<R,C,V>`. For instance `ImmutableTable<Integer,String,Boolean> process(String item) { /*...*/}`.

Collect the result i.e, merge all results (individual table may contain duplicates) and return `ImmutableTable`.

My current implementation works when there are no duplicates:

```
 final ImmutableTable<Integer, String, Boolean> result =
            itemsToProcess.parallelStream()
                    .map(item ->
                            ProcessorInstanceProvider.get()
                                    .buildTable(item))
                    .collect(toImmutableTable());

public static <R, C, V> Collector<ImmutableTable<R, C, V>,     
ImmutableTable.Builder<R, C, V>, ImmutableTable<R, C, V>> 
toImmutableTable() {
    return Collector.of(
            ImmutableTable.Builder<R, C, V>::new,
            ImmutableTable.Builder<R, C, V>::putAll,
            (
                    a,
                    b) -> a.putAll(b.build()),
            ImmutableTable.Builder::build);
  }
```

But it fails while collecting `ImmutableTable` as there are duplicate row-column entries and hence build fails.

How can i prevent build failure ? How can i use `HashBaseTable` which will work with duplicates. Something like  `T` - `ImmutableTable`, `A` - `HashBasedTable` and `R` - `ImmutableTable` with minimum memory usage?

Tried with:

```
 final HashBasedTable<Integer, String, Boolean> result =
            listOfItems.parallelStream()
            .map(item ->                              
 ProcessorInstanceProvider.get()
                    .build(item) )
                    .collect(
                            Collector.of(
                                    HashBasedTable::create,
                                    HashBasedTable::putAll,
                                    (a, b) -> {
                                        a.putAll(b);
                                        return a;
                                    }));
```

But getting runtime error:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.collect.AbstractTable
> ```

for `HashTable::putAll`.

How can we use `HashBasedTable` as accumulator to collect `ImmutablesTable`, as `HashBasedTable` overrides the existing entry with latest one and doesn't fail if we try to put duplicate entry, and return aggregated immutable table.

Comment: The `IllegalAccessError` looks like a compiler bug. Try to replace the method references by equivalent lambda expressions. I vaguely remember having seen a similar issue here.

Comment: What do you want to do with duplicates?

Comment: For duplicates, i just want to override it with latest entry, which HashBasedTable does.

Comment: Replaced them with Lambda expression and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 collector for Guava Immutable Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985659/java-8-collector-for-guava-immutable-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced method references with Lambda expression and it worked.

```
ImmutableTable.copyOf(itemList.parallelStream()
                    .map(item ->
                            ProcessorInstanceProvider.get()
                            .build(item))
                    .collect(() -> HashBasedTable.create(),
                            (a, b) -> a.putAll(b),
                            (a, b) -> a.putAll(b))
                    );
```