# Java lang IllegalAccess on collecting Guava Immutable Table via HashBasedTable accumulator

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collectors

Error while executing below code,

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class
>   com.google.common.collect.AbstractTable from class

```
 ImmutableTable.copyOf(listItemsToProcess.parallelStream()
                    .map(item ->
                            ProcessorInstanceProvider.getInstance()
                            .buildImmutableTable(item))
                    .collect(() -> HashBasedTable.create(),
                            HashBasedTable::putAll,

                            HashBasedTable<Integer, String,    
                            Boolean>::putAll)
                    );
```

> Error in coming on - HashBasedTable::putAll Using Oracle's 1.8 jre

Comment: Which line does it point to?

Comment: On HashBasedTable::putAll,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 collector for Guava ImmutableTable using HashBasedTable as accumulator gives IllegalAccessError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095205/java-8-collector-for-guava-immutabletable-using-hashbasedtable-as-accumulator-gi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, i replaced method references with Lambda expression and it worked.

```
    ImmutableTable.copyOf(itemList.parallelStream()
                    .map(item ->
                            ProcessorInstanceProvider.get()
                            .buildImmutableTable(item))
                    .collect(() -> HashBasedTable.create(),
                            (a, b) -> a.putAll(b),
                            (a, b) -> a.putAll(b))
                    );
```

Comment: The fix is probably related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100552/illegalaccesserror-when-using-a-public-method-reference-of-a-package-private-cla), but your jars are probably still out of sync. Also, don't post the same question repeatedly if you don't want to get banned.

Answer (score 5):

This is a compiler bug, related reports are

- [JDK-8152643](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152643): “Javac compiles method reference that allows results in an IllegalAccessError”
- [JDK-8059632](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059632): “Method reference compilation uses incorrect qualifying type”

Note that the first report has the status “Fixed in 8u102”, so downloading [JDK8u102](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) could solve the issue. Of course, when using a compiler other than `javac`, e.g. ECJ, you have to ensure that that compiler is up to date as well.

In either case, you have to recompile the source code, as it is a compiler issue. But then, the compiled code should even work with older JREs.

---

To explain the issue, normally, invocations should be encoded into the byte code using the compile-time type of the receiver (or the explicit type in case of `static` methods), regardless of the declaring type of the actual method implementation. So if you have a `public` class `A` inheriting the `public` method `foo` from the non-`public` class `B`, an invocation of `A.foo` should be encoded as `A.foo` rather than `B.foo`. For ordinary invocations, the compilers work that way, but for method references, `javac` (and afaik also older versions of ECJ) failed to do that correctly. So when encountering a class trying to access `B.foo` directly without having access to `B`, an `IllegalAccessError` is thrown.

It works when using a lambda expression instead, as then, the invocation is compiled into an ordinary invocation instruction, for which the compiler works correctly, within a synthetic method and a reference to that synthetic method is used when constructing an instance of the functional interface at runtime. Since the synthetic method recides within the same class, it’s always accessible.

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractTable` was introduced in Guava version 15. Take a look at your classpath configuration; you're probably using an earlier library version at runtime.