# IllegalAccessError Java 8 Method reference with package visibility class

Tags: java-8, method-reference

I have two libraries. One contains the model and the other contains something which use the model. Both are in separate jar files.

Model contains (notice that AbstractClass has package visibility)

```
public class PublicClass extends AbstractClass { }
```

.

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  private String id;
  private Long key;nter code here
}
```

Other project contains a test which use this model.

This test is working

```
@Test
public void testIssue02() {
    String message = elements.stream()
                             .map(a -> publicDao.findById(a.getId()))
                             .map(Object::toString)
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    Assert.assertEquals("...", message);
}
```

This test is failing

```
@Test
public void testIssue01() {
    //The problem is because package visibility
    String message = elements.stream()
                             .map(PublicClass::getId)
                             .map(publicDao::findById)
                             .map(Object::toString)
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    Assert.assertEquals("...", message);
}
```

The difference between both test cases is testIssue01() is using method reference to get id from PublicClass meanwhile testIssue02() is getting the property directly. The error that I got is:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.09 sec <<< FAILURE!
testIssue01(com.personal.sample.lambda.issue.SimpleIssueTest)  Time elapsed: 0.05 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.personal.sample.test.other.AbstractClass from class com.personal.sample.lambda.issue.SimpleIssueTest
at com.personal.sample.lambda.issue.SimpleIssueTest.lambda$testIssue01$0(SimpleIssueTest.java:27)
```

Both are maven projects and I only got the error when I execute in command line "mvn clean install" which is going to execute the unit tests. I also using IntelliJ to edit the project and if I run the test from IntelliJ, both test cases worked.

I have created both project in github to replicate the case:

- [method-reference-model](https://github.com/jmgoyesc/method-reference-model.git): Contains the model
- [method-reference-test](https://github.com/jmgoyesc/method-reference-test.git): Contains the unit tests

My questions are:

- Why does it work in IntelliJ and fail in console?

**R.** Thanks to Holger. In command line I was compiling with jdk 1.8.51 and there is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112471/java-lang-illegalaccess-on-collecting-guava-immutable-table-via-hashbasedtable-a/39120603#39120603).

- What is the reason of this error?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using different Java/jdk versions in IntelliJ and on the command line? It might be [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39120603/2711488) that has been fixed in JDK8, update 102. Likewise, it might be that the problem disappears when compiling with ECJ instead of `javac`; I’m not sure which compiler IntelliJ uses or whether this is configurable.

Comment: You are right. In command line I was using jdk 1.8.51 and in IntelliJ I was using jdk 1.8.111